# How to handle connection lost with exmpp?

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, exmpp

does anybody knows how to handle connection lost situation in exmpp library?

Any examples are welcome!

Answer (score 3):

So, all you have to do is to add condition in receive loop. Something like this:

```
receive
    % Here is you code
    {stream_error,'system-shutdown'} -> 
         do_something;
    % Here is you code
end.
```

Comment: It doesn't work properly with exmpp 0.9.8, but should wotk with 0.9.9